# Unable to boot after updating the kernel rhel 6.7

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, redhat-satellite

I am having a `Red Hat 6.7` running on VM which I updated with the latest version `kernel-2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64`. but after this update I received the below error:

```
kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on 
unknown block(0,0)
```

Previous version was `kernel-2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64` .

Comment: Can you get to the grub menu? Hold shift during boot if its not configured to show a menu. What have tried? Rescue mode, previous kernel?

Comment: Its working on the previous kernel, and I found that there is no initrmfs image on the system. and there is no initramfs line in the grub.conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have booted my system with my previous kernel which is working fine. while troubleshooting the system we found that there is no `initrmfs` image on the system and there is no `initramfs` line in the `grub.conf` file.

I have created the image with the below command and edited the `grub.conf` file

```
# mkinitrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64.img 2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64
```

After this change the system is working fine. possible bug from Red Hat.